# facebook connect - only one of www.mysite.com or mysite.com works?

Tags: facebook

So I've got the following in my basic apps settings for facebook connect app: Website with Facebook Login -> site URL: http://www.mysite.com

Facebook connect works fine from www.mysite.com but the problem is that if someone tries to use facebook connect from mysite.com (without the www.)I get the following error from facebook:

"Given URL is not allowed by the Application configuration.: One or more of the given URLs is not allowed by the App's settings. It must match the Website URL or Canvas URL, or the domain must be a subdomain of one of the App's domains."

Does anyone know how to fix it so that it works from www.mysite.com and mysite.com?

Comment: Set `mysite.com` as app domain.

Comment: I've updated "app domains" to mysite.com but it still won't work from mysite.com but does work from www.mysite.com.  Is there anything else I'm missing?  Is there another setting somewhere which I may have configured incorrectly?

Answer (score -1):

www.mysite.com is a sub domain of mysite.com
You should use mysite.com instead of www.mysite.com